# free group actions on a contractible topological space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory, group-actions, symmetric-groups

Let $\Sigma_k$ be the symmetric group on $k$-letters. Let $W$ be a **contractible** topological space with a **free** $\Sigma_k$-action (from the left). Let $X$ be a $CW$-complex and let $X^k$ be the Cartesian product of $k$-copies of $X$. Let $\Sigma_k$ act on $X^k$ from the right  by permuting the order of coordinates. Then we have a space
$$
W\times _{\Sigma_k} X^k=W\times X^k/ (\sigma\cdot w,a)\sim (w,a\cdot \sigma)
$$
where $w\in W, a\in X^k$ and $\sigma\in \Sigma_k$.

**Question:** whether do we have
$$
W\times _{\Sigma_k} X^k\simeq X
$$
or not? What shall I do when meeting such problems?

Comment: This is a very special case of the so-called Borel construction. The commonly accepted notation would be $W=E\Sigma_k$. The identity in the question obviously doesn't hold in general: just consider $X=*$, so that the product equals $B\Sigma_k\ne*$.

Comment: Other keywords to look for equivariant cohomology and classifying spaces

Comment: asking whether one multiplication always undoes a given power operation sounds very strange to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of scattered things to address the "how to deal with" part of the question.

---

If $X$ is connected, then probably so is $X^n$, and so you are looking at a fibration
$$ X^n \to X^n // \Sigma_n \to \mathbf{B}\Sigma_n $$
for which the Leray-Serre spectral sequences are usually called Cartan-Leray, and they look like
$$ H^{\mathrm{gp}}_p ( \Sigma_n ; H_*(X,\mathbb{k})^{\otimes n}_q ) \Rightarrow H_{p+q} (X^n // \Sigma_n ; \mathbb{k}) $$

---

In the very special case that $X$ is a strictly abelian group (that is, a product of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces), one can extend the power sequence $n\mapsto X^n$ to a functor on the category **FPartial** of finite partial functions: for $f : s \nrightarrow t$ and for $x : s \to X$, define $$ (f_* x)_j = \sum_{i : f(i) =j} x_i $$
With this data one can use some [work by Stanislaw Betley](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2002-130-12/S0002-9939-02-06763-1/) to study what happens to particular $H_p(X^n // \Sigma_n)$ as $n\gg p$.